# How to change position in array using array-move method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

My intention is to create **PuzzleGame**, example
http://migo.sixbit.org/puzzles/fifteen/

Main priority is to move **Cells** from one with ***value***, to another one ***undefined***.

Here is my function:

```
  moveCell(row, col) {
    this.puzzleTable = [];
    let actRow = 0,
      actCol = 0;

    for (let r = -1; r <= 1; r++) {
      actRow = row + r;
      if (actRow >= 0 && actRow < this.rowCount) {

        moveCells(this.puzzleTable[actRow][col], row, actRow);
      }
    }
    for (let c = -1; c <= 1; c++) {
      actCol = col + c;
      if (actCol >= 0 && actCol < this.colCount) {

        moveCells(this.puzzleTable[row][actCol], col, actCol);

      }
    }
  }
```

For example:

```
Arr[0][0] to Arr[1][1]
```

I do not want to change their **value**, I want them **swap**

What is the best practice ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap two elements inside of a 2D Array in JavaScript? (Confused about what I’m seeing from console.log in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697152/how-to-swap-two-elements-inside-of-a-2d-array-in-javascript-confused-about-wha)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could simply store the values of both cells in two temporary variables and assign them to each other accordingly.

For example:

```
var tempA=Arr[0][0];
var tempB=Arr[1][1];
Arr[0][0]=tempB;
Arr[1][1]=tempA;
```

Answer (score 0):

This swap looks a lot easier more on [How to swap two elements inside of a 2D Array in JavaScript? (Confused about what I’m seeing from console.log in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697152/how-to-swap-two-elements-inside-of-a-2d-array-in-javascript-confused-about-wha)

```js
var points = [[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200]];
console.log(points.toString());
[points[1], points[2]] = [points[2], points[1]];
```

```
var points = [[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200]];
console.log(points.toString());
[points[1], points[2]] = [points[2], points[1]];
console.log(points.toString());
```

Comment: if the question already has an answer somewhere in SO, you don't copy/paste it here, you flag as duplicated